# ModX Revo Database: Relation between member groups and document groups

Tags: database, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I'm creating some custom queries and need to figure out the relation between Member Groups and Document Groups.

My ultimate goal is to display the resources belonging to a particular User Group when a user log in. I am able to get their User ID from Sessions and so the relations I have figured out so far are:

User ID -> Member Groups Table -> `??Unknown table that pairs Member Groups with Document Groups??` -> Document Groups Table- > Resources Table

I just cant find that missing table(s)!

If any one can help me out that would be awesome!

Thanks

(ps: using Revo)

EDIT: added image for assitance

[image]

Comment: Maybe it will help you - http://forums.modx.com/thread/31499/add-new-document-to-new-resource-group-via-api

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of the built-in MODX methods to achieve this.

This is not tested and might not work, but this might be a way to do it:

```
// userGroups = membergroups
$userGroups = $user->getUserGroups();

foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) {
    $resGroups = $userGroup->getResourceGroups(); 

    foreach ($resGroups as $resGroup) {
        $resources = $resGroup->getResources();
        // merge resources into an array or something

    }
}
```

Check out **moduser.class.php**, **modusergroup.class.php**, and **modresourcegroup.class.php** to see the queries behind these methods. You might be able to adapt them to one more efficient query.

Also, if I haven't misunderstood what you want to achieve then your results should be similar to what a user would see in the resource tree in the manager when logged in?

That uses the resource/getnodes.class.php processor, which retrieves all possible resources for each context using getCollection, then loops through each and decides whether to display or not by using `$resource->checkPolicy('list')`. That might be another approach to consider.

I usually work with custom data rather than MODX resources so would be keen to hear how you get on with this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really, really old, but I came across this question looking for the answer myself. After a bit more digging I've found that it's the `access_resource_groups` table that links `document_groups` and `member_groups`

- `document_groups.id` = `access_resource_groups.target`
- `member_groups.id` = `access_resource_groups.principal`